# Need a SOAP server to run in Angular

Tags: angular, http, npm, soap, server

I am trying to implement a SOAP server in my Angular app. I have tried the following libraries, each failed with unique errors:

- https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-soap

I have implemented the [ngx-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap) library, which works for creating a client but not creating a server.

All I am looking for is a clearly laid out procedure for implementing a server to watch/listen to events from a SOAP client in my Angular app.

Comment: Angular is client side, what do you mean run a SOAP server "in" it?

Comment: I just mean I need the application itself to initialize and create a server to watch events coming from a client that I generate from a WSDL.

Comment: ...*which* application? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry if I am being unclear, let me give you all the context that I can. I have an Angular application that needs to subscribe to the events of an outside service. I currently have the ability to call the 'Subscribe' method that exists in the WSDL of the outside service, but I have no way of tracking those events that I am now subscribed to. Ultimately, I am trying to create a UI component that can display connectivity status to the outside service. If I am still unclear or missing something major please let me know.

Comment: @Kyle maybe try to use this updated ngx-soap client https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap-next